# Using rename to rename upper case to lower case and add a character

Tags: rename

On linux, using `rename` to rename multiple directories. I want to rename directories starting with higher case characters to lower case and add a special character, let's say `_` before the first letter.

For example I want to rename `Myfile` to `_myfile`

The best I came up with so far is :

```
rename -n 'y/[A-Z]/[a-z]' *
```

But when I add my character to this regular expression I get the following error :

```
rename -n 'y/[A-Z]/_[a-z]' *
Replacement list is longer than search list at (eval 90) line 1.
```

How can I add the special character to the regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
rename -n 's/^([A-Z])/_\L$1/' */
```

- `^([A-Z])` matches any uppercase letter at start, and put in captured group 1
- In the replacement, we are lowercasing (`\L`) the captured group 1 with perpending a `_`
- `*/` matches only directories

Remove `-n` for actual renaming action:

```
rename 's/^([A-Z])/_\L$1/' */
```